# Unable to connect to my ClearDB MySQL using from Heroku with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, cleardb

As title says, I am unable to connect to the database I created using ClearDB user information in the mysql workbench, however I am able to connect to my local / root database.

I inputted username, password,hostname and port. I use port 3306.

[image]